# idk why the resizing effect does not happen. ie text follows mediaQuery default sizes rather the ones set by me

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using flutter_screenUtil for adaptation

[screenshot of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVF1m.png)

I wrote this code for a text in file : page1.dart

```
Text(
       'Get More',
        style: TextStyles.subTitle,
     ),
```

and the `TextStyles.subTitle` is defined in other file :
`

```
static TextStyle subTitle = TextStyle(
    fontSize: 25.sp,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    color: Colors.white,
  );`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining a static text theme. The 25.sp does nothing more than returning a double value based on your SreenUtil configuration. Since the theme is static, this is done only once (e.g. not on every build) and will not react to changes.

You should follow the docs in order to correctly initialize ScreenUtil and the text themes. (the package looks rather messy/unclear docs + I have not used it myself, so I cannot help with this step)

Comment: After reading your comment I researched on it quite a bit. Weirdly when I restart the app the effects take place so what i think is that when the app is built the package does it thing and creates those sizes which does not change till the end. Thanks for the help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).